# Find in file then move the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, move, findstr

I have an unknown number of text files in a directory which are named as such,  `ABC1200f1234.EAU`, but they are all slightly different. The internal structure of each text file is the same, but the contents are different. Within each file there is a string `*     SERIAL NUMBER:XXXXX   *`. For each file the `6` characters following the `SERIAL NUMBER:` is different. I am trying to search each file to obtain the `6` digits following `SERIAL NUMBER:` then move that file to a directory named after the `6` digits, e.g. if the `6` digits are `A12345` then I want to create a directory named `A12345` and move the file there, then move on to the next file until all files have been moved.

The following code gets the `6` digits into `%%a` but I'm stuck on how to then move the file, before moving onto the next one. I'm sure I'm just missing one small piece of the puzzle.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
cd c\Temp

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansions
set sourcedir=c:temp
set targetdir=c:\temp\parsed

for /f "tokens=4 delims=*:" %%a in (
    'findstr /r "SERIAL NUMBER:" %sourcedir%\*'
) do (
    if exists %targetdir%\%%a (
        echo Directory already exists
    ) else mkdir %targerdir%\%%a
)
move %sourcedir%\%%a %targetdir%\%%a
)
```

I'm sure the last line is the problem because `%%a` now holds the `6` digit number, not the filename.

Please don't suggest `Powershell` as that is not an option. I also realise I can use `robocopy` and remove the check to see if the target directory exists.

Any help you can give would be most appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, `targerdir` is not what you mean to reference.

Comment: Is the serial number part always embedded in a longer line and separated from the rest by spaces, or could it be at the beginning or end of a line, or even on a separate one? is there only a single occurrence?

Comment: I have just edited your question, and in doing so indented your code at the parentheses, to clearly show you that those were unbalanced. Due to this your question body does not reflect that code. Your provided code cannot move anything with `%%a` as at that point the for loop has already closed. What your move command would try to do therefore is `move c:temp\%a c:\temp\parsed\%a`, not only are neither of those likely to exist, I'm sure that `c:temp`, should be `c:\temp`.

Comment: In addition to that `if exists` is not a valid command, it should read `if exist`. Also your `findstr` match is incorrect too. `findstr /r "SERIAL NUMBER:"` will output every line in each file which contains either the case sensitive string `SERIAL` or the case sensitive string `NUMBER:`. To find out how to use `findstr`, please open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming for this code that the serial number is directly after the colon with no white space or other characters whcih need to be removed before or after it.

```cmd
@(setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  CLS
  set "sourcedir=c:\temp"
  set "targetdir=c:\temp\parsed"
  SET "FileGlob=*.EAU"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  FOR %%_ IN (
    "%sourcedir%\%FileGlob%"
  ) DO (
    Echo=processing "%%~_"
    FOR /F "Tokens=2 delims=:" %%F IN ('
      TYPE "%%~_" ^| FIND /I "SERIAL NUMBER:"
    ') DO (
      ECHO=Found. Serial number "%%F" trimmingbany spaces
      FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%f IN ("%%~F") DO (
        ECHO=Trimmed serial number "%%~f" stored
        SET "_TmpFolder=%%F"
      )
    )
    MD "%TargetDir%\!_TmpFolder!\"
    MOVE "%%~_" "%TargetDir%\!_TmpFolder!\%%~nx_"
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Hi Ben, appreciate the quick response. When I run the code I get errors "The system cannot find the file specified" and "The filename, Directoty Name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".. The parse directory is created but running echo %TargetDir%\!_TmpFolder!\" before the MD "%TargetDir%\!_TmpFolder!\" line gives "C:\Temp\Parsed\\"

Comment: it looks like the variable that holds the 6 digit serial number is blank when it should be XXXXXX so that directory never gets created.

Comment: To answer your other question, there are no spaces between the ':' and the 6 digit number but there are blank spaces after it and also blank spaces preceding the words "SERIAL NUMBER". I did indicate this in my description but for some reason they got removed when i posted the question.

Comment: I ammended the answer to trim whitespace and echo what its doing on variable assignment.

Comment: @PaulVoller Hey Paul, Yesterday I amended the answer to trim whitespace and echo what its doing on variable assignment.  I neglected to tag you in the comment, my bad.  ALSO I am searching for files named "`[Anything].EAU`" is this correct?  Finally,   I realized i neglected to add a `/B` to the output of the DIR so that will be taken care of post haste and is likely the issue, In fact i'll just use a normal FOR loop there because why not.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any need to test if the directory you're trying to create exists. Simply do `mkdir` and pipe the output to `nul`

**NOTE!** This example assumes that the `Serial Number` is on it's own line in the file, seeing as you have not shown an actual example of your text file.

```
@echo off
set "source=c:\temp"
set "target=c:\temp\parsed"
for %%a in ("%source%\*.EAU") do for /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%i in ('type "%%~a" ^|findstr /i "serial number"') do (
    mkdir "%target%\%%i">nul 2>&1
    move "%%~a" "%target%\%%i"
)
```

As far as overwriting existing files are concerned, that is something you need to decide as I do not know your exact scenario, so did not include additional parameters to the move command.

Comment: @PaulVoller Glad it helped. Please consider reading ["`What should I do when someone answers my question?`"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on StackOverflow.